# Angular 4 keep http get in cache

Tags: angular, http, caching, browser-cache

I noticed my Angular 4 application is caching some data taken from the database when using `http.get()`.

This problem only happens with Google Chrome, when using firefox or even edge, it doesn't happen.

Basically, I have a list of purchases. When I make a new purchase, I can see the item on the list, because it's updated via redux.

However, if I refresh the page, I can't see the purchase I just made on the list. If i refresh the page using "CTRL + SHIFT + R", then the list get's updated and the purchase is shown. Keep in mind this purchase list is taken from my mysql database using php.

I don't know what may be causing this problem because the only change I've made to the HTTP service was a custom header to authenticate the user. My http get function:

```
getHeaders(): any {
    const token = this._auth.getToken();
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append(MainConfig.authToken, token);

    return headers;
}

apiGet(action: string): any {
    const header = this.getHeaders();

    return this._http.get(
        this.apiUrl + action,
        { headers: header }
    ).map(response => response.json()).do(data => {
        return data;
    }).catch(this.handleErrors);
}
```

> Note: One thing I've noticed is that this only happens online. When I'm testing it locally, on my wamp server, everything works as expected, but on the online server, the problem occur.

This is my .htaccess file and HTML header

```
// htaccess
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</ifModule>

// HTML
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: Please inspect the network request in the browser console. Does the response contain the appropriate Cache-Control-header? E. g. `Cache-Control", "no-store, must-revalidate`

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann No. But I've set the .htaccess with those properties, also the HTML file head meta tags. I've updated the question with those details. Does it help?

Comment: Please try to add `header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate")` to your php.file, which generated the database response.

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann it seems to have solved the issue. But funny thing is.. It was happening only in a few functions. Some of them works fine.. But some keep caching its data. Ex.: When searching for new products, it's not cached. But on personal data, it's cached. Only difference is, personal data goes trough a redux store and the products list don't.